# Terraform in Azure DevOps Pipeline Timeout Obtaining Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

When I call terraform plan from within an Azure DevOps pipeline I receive:
Error building ARM Config: obtain subscription(xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) from Azure CLI: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1

I am setting the ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_CLIENT_SECRET, ARM_TENENT_ID, and ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID environment variables to the appropriate values and the pipeline step reflects the proper subscription in the "subscritpion(...)" above.

I can manually run terraform plan after using az login with the Service Principal information without issue.

What could be the cause of the timeout, or is the timeout error one of those weird messages not actually related to the source of the problem?

Pipeline Definition:

```
trigger: 
- development

variables:
  - group: Variable Group

stages:
- stage: Stage Name

  variables:
    ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(clientId)
    ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(clientSecret)
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(subscriptionId)
    ARM_TENANT_ID: $(tenantId)

  jobs:
  - job: Terraform

    pool:
      name: Self-Hosted-Image

    steps:
    - checkout: self

    - script: |
        sudo apt-get install wget unzip -y
        wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.14.0/terraform_0.14.0_linux_amd64.zip
        unzip -o terraform*.zip
        sudo mv terraform /usr/local/bin/
        terraform --version
      workingDirectory: 'build'
      displayName: "Install Terraform v0.14.0"

    - script: |
        wget --no-check-certificate -O terragrunt https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download/v0.26.4/terragrunt_linux_amd64
        sudo mv terragrunt /usr/local/bin/
        sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/terragrunt
        terragrunt --version
      workingDirectory: 'build'
      displayName: 'Install Terragrunt v0.26.4'

    - script: |  
        curl -vvvkLs "$(curl -Lks https://api.github.com/repos/terraform-linters/tflint/releases/latest | grep -o -E "https://.+?_linux_amd64.zip")" -o tflint.zip
        unzip -o tflint.zip
        rm tflint.zip
        sudo chmod +x tflint
        sudo mv tflint /usr/local/bin/tflint
      workingDirectory: 'build'
      displayName: 'Install Terraform Lint Latest'

    - script: |
        terraform init -input=false
      workingDirectory: 'terraform'
      displayName: 'Terraform Init'

    - script: |
        terraform validate
      workingDirectory: 'terraform'
      displayName: 'Terraform Validate'

    #- script: |
    #    terraform fmt -check
    #  workingDirectory: 'terraform'
    #  displayName: 'Terraform FMT'

    - script: |
        tflint
      workingDirectory: 'terraform'
      displayName: 'TFLint' 

    - script: |
        terragrunt plan -out=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tfplan -input=false
      workingDirectory: 'environments/development'
      displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')) #Do not run this step if the build is a PR validation
  
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: artifact-name'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: drop-folder
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')) #Do not run this step if the build is a PR validation
```

Everything works until it hits the Terraform Plan step

Run Log:

```
2020-12-15T17:43:00.9659003Z ##[section]Starting: Terraform Plan
2020-12-15T17:43:00.9664806Z ==============================================================================
2020-12-15T17:43:00.9665038Z Task         : Command line
2020-12-15T17:43:00.9665284Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2020-12-15T17:43:00.9665497Z Version      : 2.178.0
2020-12-15T17:43:00.9665658Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-12-15T17:43:00.9665912Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2020-12-15T17:43:00.9666180Z ==============================================================================
2020-12-15T17:43:01.0904669Z Generating script.
2020-12-15T17:43:01.0919946Z Script contents:
2020-12-15T17:43:01.0922423Z terragrunt plan -out=/agent/_work/1/a/tfplan -input=false
2020-12-15T17:43:01.0924242Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-12-15T17:43:01.0972091Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /agent/_work/_temp/1ef04c65-2b59-471c-9b10-61b4fb875bf6.sh
2020-12-15T17:43:01.1138885Z [terragrunt] [/agent/_work/1/s/environments/development] 2020/12/15 17:43:01 Running command: terraform --version
2020-12-15T17:43:01.1687390Z [terragrunt] 2020/12/15 17:43:01 Terraform version: 0.14.0
2020-12-15T17:43:01.1688355Z [terragrunt] 2020/12/15 17:43:01 Reading Terragrunt config file at /agent/_work/1/s/environments/development/terragrunt.hcl
2020-12-15T17:43:01.1753684Z [terragrunt] 2020/12/15 17:43:01 Downloading Terraform configurations from file:///agent/_work/1/s into /agent/_work/1/s/environments/development/.terragrunt-cache/8zRFFg84e6PM_O2Mh9L28GOIGjk/vpPFdkCXP2IXDc5sYKtN70MIoZ0
2020-12-15T17:43:01.2168986Z [terragrunt] 2020/12/15 17:43:01 Copying files from /agent/_work/1/s/environments/development into /agent/_work/1/s/environments/development/.terragrunt-cache/8zRFFg84e6PM_O2Mh9L28GOIGjk/vpPFdkCXP2IXDc5sYKtN70MIoZ0/terraform
2020-12-15T17:43:01.2173570Z [terragrunt] 2020/12/15 17:43:01 Setting working directory to /agent/_work/1/s/environments/development/.terragrunt-cache/8zRFFg84e6PM_O2Mh9L28GOIGjk/vpPFdkCXP2IXDc5sYKtN70MIoZ0/terraform
2020-12-15T17:43:01.2175469Z [terragrunt] 2020/12/15 17:43:01 Generated file /agent/_work/1/s/environments/development/.terragrunt-cache/8zRFFg84e6PM_O2Mh9L28GOIGjk/vpPFdkCXP2IXDc5sYKtN70MIoZ0/terraform/backend.tf.
2020-12-15T17:43:01.2180745Z [terragrunt] [/agent/_work/1/s/environments/development] 2020/12/15 17:43:01 Initializing remote state for the azurerm backend
2020-12-15T17:43:01.2181686Z [terragrunt] [/agent/_work/1/s/environments/development] 2020/12/15 17:43:01 Running command: terraform init
2020-12-15T17:43:01.2788920Z 
2020-12-15T17:43:01.2790448Z [0m[1mInitializing the backend...[0m
2020-12-15T17:43:14.4169389Z [31m
2020-12-15T17:43:14.4182834Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError building ARM Config: obtain subscription([ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID]) from Azure CLI: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1[0m
2020-12-15T17:43:14.4183877Z 
2020-12-15T17:43:14.4184450Z [0m[0m[0m
2020-12-15T17:43:14.4199158Z [terragrunt] 2020/12/15 17:43:14 Hit multiple errors:
2020-12-15T17:43:14.4199828Z exit status 1
2020-12-15T17:43:14.4300174Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2020-12-15T17:43:14.4318001Z ##[section]Finishing: Terraform Plan
```

Comment: Hi, Which agent are you using? Hosted agent or self-hosted agent? According to your description, it seems that it works on locally. Could you try self-hosted agent and share the result here? In addition, please also share the detail logs and pipeline definition here. Thanks.

Comment: I am using the Hosted agent. I will try a self-hosted. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I switched to a self-hosted agent. The terraform plan step took a little longer, this time, but still produced the same error.
I added the pipeline definition and log to the original post.